# Why does $(A-I)^2=0$ implies all eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Why does $(A-I)^2=0$ implies all eigenvalues of $A$ are $1$? Here $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix.

Write down the characteristic polynomial of $A$, which is $p(A)=(t-\lambda_1)(t-\lambda_2)\dots(t-\lambda_n)$. $1$ is one of its eigenvalues, but why all $\lambda$ are $1$?

Comment: Hint: diagonalize A

Comment: @brennan A may not be diagonalizable.

Comment: @brennan Hint: give better hints

Comment: The Cayley Hamilton theorem can be very helpful to your question

Comment: @imranfat not directly. Really, one should consider the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, oh yes, I see now. I was thinking of $\lambda^2-2*\lambda+1=0$...a consequence..

Comment: This is one more hit for the _first fundamental fact about eigenvectors and polynomials_ (in my opinion), which is that if a vector $v$ is eigenvector for a linear operator $T$ for eigenvalue$~\lambda$ (i.e., is $T(v)=\lambda v$, then $P[T](v)=P[\lambda]v$ for **any** polynomial $P$. I think it is worth learning this by heart as, it comes in handy very often (much more so than the way deeper Cayley-Hamilton theorem). You may even come to consider this fact to be obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. What can you say about $(A-I)^2x$?

Comment: $(\lambda -1)^2x=0$? hence $\lambda =1$?

Comment: Yes. Though it should be noted that $x \neq 0$.

Comment: That's right, and we know that $x \neq 0$ because $x$ is an eigenvector

Answer (score 4):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ divides any polynomial that $A$ satisfies. $A$ satisfies the polynomial $(x-1)^2$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $A$ is either $(x-1)$ or $(x-1)^2$.

> Fact: The the eigenvalues of $A$ are exactly the roots of the minimal polynomial.

Thus $1$ is the only eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and that $m$ is a polynomial such that $m(A) = 0$. Then $(x-\lambda)$ is a factor of $m$.

To see this, note that if $v \not = 0$ is an eigenvector associated to $\lambda$, then $0 = m(A)(v) = m(\lambda)v$, meaning that $m(\lambda) = 0$.